# How to add vertical/horizontal values in a `ListLogLogPlot `?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have to plot on a log-log scale `y=f(x)` for these data

```
x = Table[s, {s, 0, 100, 0.1}];
y = Table[Exp[s - 1], {s, 0, 100, 0.1}];
data = Transpose@{x, y};

ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 100}]
```

[image]

I would like to add on the same plot the vertical and horizontal lines: `x=1`, `x=3`

How to do it please?

`MAT Version : 13.0`

Comment: Have you seen `GridLines` already?

Comment: @J. M., yes but I don't want the `GridLines`.

Comment: `Show[ListLogLogPlot[{{1,3},{100,3}},Joined->True], ListLogLogPlot[{{1,1},{1,9}},Joined->True], ListLogLogPlot[{{3,1},{3,9}},Joined->True], ListLogLogPlot[data,Joined->True,PlotRange->{0.1,100}]]`

Comment: Perhaps you too quickly discarded the suggestion of @J.M.? You can have just two vertical grid lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InfiniteLine` can be used on plots.  In this example we will use the "point, direction" form of `InfiniteLine`. The coordinates of the point passed to `InfiniteLine` must be adjusted when the plot scales are logarithmic.

For two vertical lines given by $x=1$ and $x=3$ and a horizontal line given by $y=2$ we can code

```
abscissas = {1, 3};
ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 100},
 Epilog -> {InfiniteLine[{Log[#], 1}, {0, 1}] & /@ abscissas,
 InfiniteLine[{1, Log[2]}, {1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

My intuition was to use `Log[10,x]` for the scaling, but using base 10 was wrong.  It's the natural log that gives the correct scaling.

For a diagonal line through $x,y=\{5,10\}$, code `InfiniteLine[{Log[5], Log[10]}, {1, 1}]`

Note that the *direction* used in `InfiniteLine[pt,dir]` is not logarithmically scaled.

Comment: Thank you @LouisB , please can you add in the same plot the horizontal line `y=2`?

Comment: It's great @LouisB , thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

I still believe that `GridLines` is convenient.

```
ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 100}, 
 GridLines -> {{{1, Directive[Red, Opacity[1]]}, {3, 
     Directive[Red, Thick, Opacity[1]]}}, {{2, 
     Directive[Thick, Opacity[1]]}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @cvgmt.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
x = Table[s, {s, 0, 100, 0.1}];
y = Table[Exp[s - 1], {s, 0, 100, 0.1}];
data = Transpose@{x, y};

ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 100}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Line[{{{Log@1, -3}, {Log@1, -2}}, {{Log@3, -3}, {Log@
        3, -2}}, {{-2.6, Log@4}, {-2.4, Log@4}}}]}]
```

[image]

If you want horizontal/vertical lines, simple make the lines longer:

```
ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 100}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Line[{{{Log@1, -3}, {Log@1, 100}}, {{Log@3, -3}, {Log@3, 
       100}}, {{-2.6, Log@4}, {100, Log@4}}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Daniel Huber thank you, but sorry I wanted to draw the vertical lines `x=1, x=3`, not the points.

Comment: Simply make the lines longer. I added this to my anwer.